# How can I open pdf from my app from remote URL in Android?

Tags: android

I want to open PDF in my app from Remote URL.

```
 Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.wsa);
        final String googleDocsUrl = "http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=";

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(googleDocsUrl +path), "text/html");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  WebView webView=(WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.WebView01);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.eli.sdsu.edu%2Fcourses%2Ffall09%2Fcs696%2Fnotes%2FAndroid13Web.pdf");
        

        try {
            startActivity(intent);
        } 
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(ReaderActivity.this, 
                "No Application Available to View PDF", 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to provide mime type as application/pdf:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("http://14.140.41.194/monali/i.pdf"), "application/pdf");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```